# getting html from filter and appending in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Hi I want to know how can I get a data from filter and append it in my html. I am getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

**HTML**

```
<span id='securedata'></span>
<script>
        window.onscroll = () => {
            if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'purple';
                <!--my problem is -->
                $('#securedata').append("{% recommend_community_first request.user.pk %}");

            }
            else {
                document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'white';
            }
        }

</script>
```

templatetags/load_recommendation.py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('community/recommend_not_recommend.html')
def recommend_community_first(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    community = Community.objects.all().order_by('-popularity')[:6]
    post = Post.objects.filter(community__in=[i.pk for i in community],video__isnull=True).order_by('-created')
    return {'posts':post,'moi':user}
```

how can I append that data from my filter without any error. Thanks

Comment: that's Python exception, right? Can you provide the whole traceback, not just the error message, and your relevant Python code?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko nope the error is from js console on chrome

Comment: what's the output of the template tag`recommend_community_first`?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko it is a html content with posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To access Django template variables in JavaScript**

Just do like this:

```
<script>
    let my_url = "{% url 'recommend_community_first' request.user.pk %}";
    // Or if it is {{ }} kind
    let my_var = '{{ context_name_variable }}';

    // Here you can use these variable
    $('#securedata').append(my_url);
</script>
```

**The trick** is to always use quote (`''` or `""`) on your variable in the JS section.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is not working i got a error Uncaught "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".maybe the problem is how i pass the variable in the filter "request.user.pk "

Comment: I am getting the data when i go to view-source in chrome and the error above.the data is not appended to the id.

Comment: Yes i updated the answer, the javascript variable must be exactly the same as Django template variable , but surrounded by `" "` or `' '`. Here i think that the error is how we wrote the django url template variable (`{% url recommend_community_first request.user.pk %}`) but **it must be** `{% url 'recommend_community_first' request.user.pk %}`. Note the `' '` around the url name.

Comment: it is not url it is just a custom_filter in my templatetags.

Comment: How my bad !!!  Can you show me the definition of this filter tag ?

Comment: **Access to the user object in Django template using** `{{ user }}` variable. **NOT** `{{ request.user}}`. Your template tags is now `{% url recommend_community_first user.pk %}`. But **be sure that the user is logged in**.

Comment: the problem is not there.when i rendered the data it is shown in the js console.the problem is from somewhere else.thanks for your time.